# how to remove elements in list of lists of nested lists?

Tags: r, list, nested

How can I go from

```
x <- list(p1 = list(type='A',score=list(c1=10,c2=8,c3=data.frame(a=1, b=3, c=5))),
       p2 = list(type='B',score=list(c1=9,c2=9,c3=data.frame(a=2, b=2))),
       p3 = list(type='B',score=list(c1=9,c2=7,c3=data.frame(a=2, b=2))))
```

to a list without the "c3" elements that are data frames?

Preferably in a `tidyverse`-friendly way or something I can put in the middle of a pipeline.

I've already tried list.remove, nested lapply, rapply, Filter, but can't seem to get them to work... and I don't want to unlist my nested list structure.

(Edit: sorry, I had a typo in the sample data in my original question (see below), but great if your solution works in both cases!)

```
x <- list(p1 = list(type='A',score=list(c1=10,c2=8,c3=data.frame(a=1, b=3, c=5))),
       p2 = list(type='B',score=list(c1=9,c2=9,c3=data.frame(a=2, b=2)),
       p3 = list(type='B',score=list(c1=9,c2=7,c3=data.frame(a=2, b=2)))))
```

Comment: Did you intend for *p3* to be an element inside *p2* and not at the *p* level?

Comment: Oops, you're right, I meant p1 p2 p3 to be at the same level, but either way, I would prefer something that works for any kind of complicated nesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the right scenario to use `modify_depth`, which functions as a shortcut for chains of `modify` to access deep nested lists. `modify` has an advantage over `map` in this problem because it will preserve the type of the input instead of coercing everything to lists, which may be relevant if you have vector elements of your list structure.

Using your given input (with a `p3` element inside rather than on the same level as `p2`), the dataframe elements at the second and third levels are `discard`ed as below. In order to search all levels of the nested list, we can set up a `while` loop to iterate through the levels, discarding dataframes as we go. We need `.ragged = TRUE` to deal with errors with list depth. This version searches bottom up but you could change it to search top down as well.

```r
library(tidyverse)
x <- list(
  p1 = list(type = "A", score = list(c1 = 10, c2 = 8, c3 = data.frame(a = 1, b = 3, c = 5))),
  p2 = list(
    type = "B", score = list(c1 = 9, c2 = 9, c3 = data.frame(a = 2, b = 2)),
    p3 = list(type = "B", score = list(c1 = 9, c2 = 7, c3 = data.frame(a = 2, b = 2)))
  )
)

remove_dataframes <- function(input_list) {
  current_list <- input_list
  current_depth <- vec_depth(current_list)
  # current_depth <- max_depth
  while (current_depth > 1) {
    current_list <- modify_depth(
      .x = current_list,
      .depth = current_depth,
      .f = ~ discard(., is.data.frame),
      .ragged = TRUE
    )
  current_depth <- current_depth - 1
  }
  return(current_list)
}

x %>%
  remove_dataframes %>%
  glimpse
#> List of 2
#>  $ p1:List of 2
#>   ..$ type : chr "A"
#>   ..$ score:List of 2
#>   .. ..$ c1: num 10
#>   .. ..$ c2: num 8
#>  $ p2:List of 3
#>   ..$ type : chr "B"
#>   ..$ score:List of 2
#>   .. ..$ c1: num 9
#>   .. ..$ c2: num 9
#>   ..$ p3   :List of 2
#>   .. ..$ type : chr "B"
#>   .. ..$ score:List of 2
```

<sup>Created on 2019-02-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Do you mean the one in the lowest `p3` level or something else?

Comment: yes, I'm trying to get rid of all the c3 data.frames. I tried using your code for the dataset where p1 p2 p3 are at the same level, but in both cases, I get "Error in range[1] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable"

Comment: Updated to address the multiple layers.

Comment: I'm still getting "Error in range[1] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable" for some reason. I know you're using reprex so it's weird... Thanks for showing me the purrr functions modify, modify_depth, and discard

Answer (score 3):

You can write your own function to do this:

```
check = function(x,name){
  m = names(x)%in% name
  x = if(any(m)) x[!m] else x
  if(is.list(x)) sapply(x,check,name)
  else x
}

dput(check(x,'c3'))
list(p1 = list(type = "A", score = list(c1 = 10, c2 = 8)), p2 = list(
    type = "B", score = list(c1 = 9, c2 = 9), p3 = list(type = "B", 
        score = list(c1 = 9, c2 = 7))))
```

This is also vecotized in that it can discard all that you need. eg try `check(x,c('c1','c3'))`

Comment: Cool, I should have practiced recursion more in programming class! I refined your answer so that the list structure is maintained and the criteria is is.data.frame instead.
removeDataFramesFromList <- function(x) {
  m <- sapply(x, is.data.frame)
  x <- if(any(m)) x[!m] else x
  if(is.list(x)) lapply(x, check) else x
}

Answer (score 2):

Here is another alternative using `rrapply()` in the `rrapply`-package that works for arbitrary levels of nesting:

```r
library(rrapply)

x1 <- rrapply(x, condition = function(x, .xparents) !any(.xparents == "c3"), how = "prune")
str(x1)  
#> List of 3
#>  $ p1:List of 2
#>   ..$ type : chr "A"
#>   ..$ score:List of 2
#>   .. ..$ c1: num 10
#>   .. ..$ c2: num 8
#>  $ p2:List of 2
#>   ..$ type : chr "B"
#>   ..$ score:List of 2
#>   .. ..$ c1: num 9
#>   .. ..$ c2: num 9
#>  $ p3:List of 2
#>   ..$ type : chr "B"
#>   ..$ score:List of 2
#>   .. ..$ c1: num 9
#>   .. ..$ c2: num 7
```